# Problemas para encontrar tabela no sql

Tags: sql-server

Quando eu uso `o Select * From table_x` e vou por minha tabela, o `SQL` não encontra a tabela indicada?

Comment: Está na database correta?

Comment: Qual o retorno que você recebe quando manda excutar seu comando? Ou por acaso você está falando do auto complete do SGBD?

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "o SQL não acha ela" ? você está se referindo ao intellisense? que te dá "dicas" dos objetos, comandos e funções? Ou quando você roda o comando "select * from tabela", onde a tabela realmente exista na sua database, o sql-server retorna um erro? Envie mais detalhes por favor.

Comment: Tente fazer.

`USE SeuBanco
GO

SELECT *  FROM dbo.Tabela`

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente você criou a tabela no contexto do seu usuário

Faça a seguinte verificação

```
//esse é o padrão
Select * from banco.dbo.tabela
//Sua tabela esta assim provavelmente
Select * from banco.seu_usuario.tabela
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente passar no comando o nome da base de dados, também, ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
SELECT * FROM seu_banco.minha_tabela;
```

As vezes que tive problemas relacionados, usei assim e funcionou!